# JQuery ajax post request gets cancelled on options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I've got a Node.js backend which I set up to receive post requests to a given url. Everything works great, the post is successful, when I do the post via the Advanced Rest Client Chrome Extension. No errors in my backend code. When I do a post from my client application, however, the call gets cancelled on the Options request. I know that often has to do with incorrect headers or cross-origin issues, however I've set up my server to the following specifications:

Node App:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
```

Cient-side Code:

```
var sendObj = {};

sendObj.firstName = firstName;
sendObj.lastName = lastName;
sendObj.address = address;
sendObj.phone = phone;
sendObj.email = email;
sendObj.birthday = birthday;
sendObj.gender = gender;
sendObj.codingExperience = codingExperience;
sendObj.whyInterested = whyInterested;
sendObj.referralInformation = referralInformation;
if(referralInformation != "Other"){
    sendObj.otherReferral = "N/A";
}
else{
    sendObj.otherReferral = otherReferral;
}

var url = "http://url-to-server/postendpoint";

if(errors == false){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType:"application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
        },
        data: sendObj,
        success: successOther()
    });
}
else{
    alert("Please fill in all the fields before submitting.");
}
```

I've searched through my request to see if there's anything different from what is being sent in Advanced Rest Client, but I'm not finding anything. Here is the response info from ARC.

Request Headers:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1462765942.1389934532
```

I'd love any help I can get to figure out why this might not be working on my client app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `X-Requested-With` as an allowed header. jQuery adds this header when it sends the AJAX request.

Comment: This must've been it. I didn't know jQuery adds on extra headers beyond those I've specified. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with node but this might help:

https://gist.github.com/nilcolor/816580

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do anything. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I still haven't found out what the issue is exactly. However, I did find out that it has something to do with my JQuery call. I decided to use an Angular.js `$http.post()` request instead for the post to the server and everything worked beautifully. So I'm guessing I somehow set up my headers wrong in the JQuery post, because that's a common thing to cause the OPTIONS request to fail, but things seem to be working perfectly now! If anybody would have any idea as to exactly what I'm doing wrong that would be fantastic to find out!

Comment: This works too. See Rob's answer. The Angular.js post request is only adding the headers I specify, while the jQuery one is adding on an extra one I didn't know about.